# SQLAlchemy, FreeTDS & MSSQL DBAPI error: Conversion between 47 and -1 datatypes is not supported

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, sqlalchemy, freetds

I've created some Python code on an Ubuntu 14.04.3 machine that uses SQLAlchemy & FreeTDS to access a MSSQL database and it works flawlessly. When I deployed this onto a CentOS 6.6 machine the exact same code fails with:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (Error) ('Layer: 2, Origin: 1\ncs_convert: cslib user api layer: external error: Conversion between 47 and -1 datatypes is not supported.'
```

I am stumped. I've checked the freetds.conf, odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini and the relevant entries are identical.

- Ubuntu machine: Python 2.7.6
- Ubuntu machine: SQLAlchemy 0.8.4
- CentOS machine: Python 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)
- CentOS machine: SQLAlchemy 0.9.7

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have subsequently worked around the issue by using a manual query in my SQLAlchemy code where I simply use plain SQL and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Which FreeTDS version are you using on each machine? From my experience, CentOS 6 uses FreeTDS 0.91 and Ubuntu uses 0.95. These versions handle date fields differently, with FreeTDS 0.95 supporting the new MS date fields introduced in 2008. You can:

- Force TDS Version in all of your settings to be 7.1 or
- (preferred) upgrade to FreeTDS 0.95 on CentOS 6, which would require a build from source.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will do some investigation and let you know.